# left floating <img> and <ul> in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, joomla

I'm having an issue with unordered list in internet explorer (9,10 & 11 as far is i know). I have an image that floats to the left, and there's an unorderd list on the right. In chrome, safari, firefox the bullets show on the right side of the image,  where the list items are. In IE the bullets show on the left of the image. BTW it's a site made with joomla if that matters.

Anyone knows whats wrong with my code? thanks

[How it should be: chrome, firefox, safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYUn9.png)

[result in Internet Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OwgP.png)

html:

```
<div id="productinfo" class="tab-pane rl_tabs-pane nn_tabs-pane active" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="tab-productinfo" role="tabpanel">

<h2 class="rl_tabs-title nn_tabs-title">

<div>
<img alt="garageline" src="/images/gamma-artikel/garageline.jpg">
</div>
<h4>Product information Wooden Garage</h4>

<ul>
<li>Panel structure thickness plank 18, 22, 28 mm</li>
<li>Door width single ca. 0.80 m</li>
<li>Door height ca. 1.92 m</li>
<li>Wall height ca. 2.10 m</li>
<li>Roofing shingles (of your choice: black, brown, red, green)</li>
<li>Roofing (flat roof) (wooden subroof, metal plate , PVC-gutter)</li>
<li>Goods on pallets, packed in PVC foil</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
 img {
  display: inline !important;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-right: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-inline-start: 20px !important;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: match-parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, your img floats right and your ul is on display:block.. IE never loved that type of thing, floats escape the buffer and IE+ buffer logic = sadness and sorrow. just make sure you give both elements a width and both are in float, then put a clear:both div under and you should obtain your result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
ul {
  float: right;
}
```

and width for the img (and for ul optional)